# How to make a python script containing file paths independently executable as well as importable?

Tags: python

There are several filepaths in a python script such as

```
ner_model = '../jd_ner_june19.ser.gz'
word2vec_model = '..\\Word2Vec\\model-100-5-6-11June.pkl'
```

When the script is imported and used by another script for example a script in the parent directory , FileNotFoundError occurs.

Is there a standardized way to handle such situations ? The end goal is to deploy the package in a docker

Comment: Use absolute paths

Comment: @dcg Since the end goal is deploy the app in a docker , I don't feel should be using absolute paths . Also , using absolute paths makes running the app on other's machines difficult

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compose the file name as the following, assuming those paths are relative to your script filename:

```
import os.path

myfile = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'my/file/path.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to look at [Pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) which provides an OO way of dealing with paths in an OS-independent way.

Comment: A code snippet of how to use the Pathlib library in this scenario would be really useful